# Jmeter truncating the request

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create a script, one of the request sends a json payload with '\\' but JMeter seems to truncate '\' from the request. Please see the details below:

Original Request(from website):

> {\"payloadJSON\":\"{\\"formFields\\":[{\\"fieldId\\":\\"replaceItems\\",\\"stringValue\\":\\"

Actual Request(from JMeter):

> {\"payloadJSON\":\"{\"formFields\":[{\"fieldId\":\"replaceItems\",\"stringValue\":\"

I have tried adding '\' before '\\' but it doesnt work.
Need advise to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter is a Java application and uses Java Strings. Therefore you have to encode a `\` with `\\`. So for two backslashes you need: `\\\\`.

Comment: Hi,it worked fine. At some places there were 7 '\', i had to add 6 more to make it work.Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: When you're satisfied you can mark the answer as correct :)